# Explanation of the UPER encoding of an extensible sequence

Tags: codec, asn.1

I have the following ASN.1 SEQENCE type, with the following value, and that produces the below encoding in UPER. I'm interested in why the encoding looks like it does, particularly the start as it's what's consistent across multiple compilers and encoders  (both open source and commercial), but from reading the spec I don't understand how it's possible.

The first byte is `1110 0000`, and I don't understand how the start is `111` in the encoding, as from looking at the sequence and value, it feels like it should be `11`, as the first bit is the extension addition presence flag, and the second bit is the first boolean, however I don't know where the third `1` comes from, as from reading the X.691 specification, the next thing should be the normally small integer length determinant of the bitfield of extension additions, and since the number of extension additions is **3**, the next bit should be zero to indicate that it's a bitfield of less than 64 bits, followed by the bitfield, but in every implementation the third bit is `1`, is there something I'm missing from the spec that would explain why the third bit is `1` and not `0`?

**Edit:**
The second byte is `0111 0000` which would imply a bit field length of maybe one (`1`), or three `11`, but given the recent answer indicating that there is fact only two extension additions, I'm confused as what the length determinant is supposed to be here for the extensions bitfield.

#### Schema And Value

```
  G ::= SEQUENCE {
              a BOOLEAN,
              ...,
              [[
              b BOOLEAN
              ]],
              [[
              c BOOLEAN
              ]],
              ...,
              d BOOLEAN
            }

value ::= G {
  a TRUE,
  b TRUE,
  c TRUE,
  d TRUE
}
```

#### encoding (hexadecimal):

```
E070180018000A
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The components "a" and "d" constitute the extension root of your sequence type. Note that the second ellipsis marks the end of the extension additions and the beginning of the second part of the extension root.

In this sequence type, there are two extension addition groups. The first group contains "b" and the second group contains "c". The first bit of the PER encoding is '1' because the sequence value contains one or more extensions. The second bit of the PER encoding contains the encoding of component "a" and the third bit contains the encoding of component "d" (not "b").

Here is an explanation of this encoding:

```
offset (bits), length (bits), description

 0, 1, preamble
    0, 1, extension bit ('1': the sequence value is extended)
 1, 1, root component 'a' ('1': TRUE)
 2, 1, root component 'd' ('1': TRUE)
 3, 1, format of the length of the extension bitmap ('0': a "normally small" length)
 4, 6, length of the extension bitmap ('000001': the length is 1+1=2 bits) --see note below
10, 2, extension bitmap ('11')
12, 8, length of the first extension ('00000001': the length is 1 octet)
20, 8, first extension
    20, 1, component 'b' ('1': TRUE)
    21, 7, padding ('0000000')
28, 8, length of the second extension ('00000001': the length is 1 octet)
36, 8, second extension
    36, 1, component 'c' ('1': TRUE)
    36, 7, padding ('0000000')
44, 4, final padding of the complete encoding ('0000')

total length: 48 bits

11100000 01110000 00011000 00000000 00011000 00000000
E0 70 18 00 18 00
```

Note: A "normally small length" is a length determinant that is restricted to the range 1..64. Such a length value must be encoded by encoding the length minus one into a 6-bit unsigned integer field.

Comment: yep, 2 bits for 2 booleans and 54 bits for 2 booleans in the extensions ... would you care to expand your answer and explain the logic of the encoding after the 3 first bits ? that would be great (I think the 0A in the question is not part of it)

Comment: The length of the encoding is 44 bits, which is padded out to 48 bits because it's a "complete encoding". The final byte '0A' shown in the question is not part of it.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I did not realise that the second `...` meant the end, and the fields after that were in the root component list, I had assumed that meant another extension (e.g. version 3's extensions).

Comment: Also even though it's not part of the question, I would definitely appreciate an explanation of the final byte '0A', as that is something that I've found to be different between compilers.

Comment: could it be that 0A is a line feed caracter ?

Comment: I guess it could be but it would be odd, this specific output is from asn1.io's UPER output, so maybe the file output there is designed to output a line feed character, but that would be quite odd (though not the oddest thing given ASN.1)

Comment: Also the second byte also confuses me, it's `70`/`0111 0000`, which to me looks like length determinant of 1 or a length determinant of 3, a length determinant of 2 would be `10` so there should be a `0` in between the ones somewhere that's clearly not there.

Comment: I also tried with asn1.io ... my file is 6 bytes long  and I don't see a 0x0A when I open it with an hex editor. Like you, I'm confused when I try to reconcile the specification X.691 (encoding a sequence) and the output from asn1.io

Comment: I've added a bounty for an answer with the complete explanation of every byte / field.

Comment: The final 0A that you are getting is not part of the encoding. Most likely it's a line feed added by some tool along the way.

Comment: @Alessandro Thank you for your detailed response, however I'm very confused how `('000001': the length is 1+1=2 bits)` this is two bits. I know there's a note in 19.8 of X.691 that says the bitfield cannot be zero, but I don't see anything that says it has a lower bound of `1..`.

Comment: See X.691, clause 11.9.3.4 Where the length determinant is a normally small length and "n" is less than or equal to 64, a single-bit bit-field shall be appended to the field-list with the bit set to 0, and the value "n–1" shall be encoded as a non-negative-binary-integer into a 6-bit bit-field. 

It says, "the value "n–1" shall be encoded", etc. So, for example, when the length is 2, the value 1 shall be encoded.

Answer (score 2):

(@Alessandro answered first)

Another way to show the encoding (as used in x.691 appendix)

```
Type reorganized in canonical order
G ::= SEQUENCE {
              a BOOLEAN,
              d BOOLEAN,
              ...,
              b BOOLEAN,
              c BOOLEAN
            }



Bits of the encoding. '.' is the octet boundary

1 There are extensions
1 a is TRUE
1 d is TRUE
00000.01 There are 2 extensions (length encoded as normally small)
1 b is present
1 c is present
0000.0001 length of b (1)
1000.0000 value of b TRUE
0000.0001 length of c(1)
1000.0000 value of c TRUE
0000 padding
```